# Regular expression for specific special characters not working for back slash

Tags: jquery, regex

I have to validate these special characters `\/:*>"<>|` and remove that from the html input(textbox).This is my code for that.

```
$(divPopupMedia).find("#txtItemName").on('input', function () {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[\/:*>"<>|]/g, ''));
});
```

All the characters mentioned except back slash(\) is removed. I modified the code with the expression `/[\\/:*>"<>|]/g`.Now it shows script error in my editor(visual studio 2010) as *`unterminated string constant`* .I need to remove the back slash too. In what way should I modify the code.

Comment: You have to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash otherwise it will accept it as a part of the pattern.

```
/[\\\/:*>"<>|]/g
```

Your code should be:

```
$(divPopupMedia).find("#txtItemName").on('input', function () {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[\\\/:*>"<>|]/g, ''));
});
```

[Test @ Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lA5sN4/1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to double up the \ to escape it.

```
/[\\\/:*>"<>|]/g
```